# 配列ではなくオブジェクトを「for … of」でループするにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

下記を「for … of」でループするには、どうすれば良いでしょうか？
・配列でないと無理？

```
 var hoge = {"area23": "東京", "area47": "沖縄"};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for..of` は Iterator と組み合わせるものであり、**プロパティ名の列挙にはこれまで通り `for..in` を使う必要があります。** Array や Map は Iterator を提供している（Iterable）ので `for...of` が使えます。

これまでプロパティの列挙が `for..in` でできていた一方で、 arguments のような配列モドキや独自のコレクションを `Array.prototype.forEach` のように反復処理する方法はありませんでした。一部の処理系では `Array.forEach` などの一般化した実装も提供していましたが、これは配列のように `length` プロパティとインデックスアクセスを用いるものですから、ES6 で登場する Generator のように要素数がわからないオブジェクトでは利用できません。

そこで、「次の要素に進む」「現在の値」「続きがあるかどうか」のみを使った Iterator が生まれ、それを用いた foreach のようなものが `for...of` 、ということになります。

ちなみに、ES6 の `for..in` は[「プロパティ名を列挙するイテレータ」](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate)を生成し、それを反復する、といった書き方になっていました。

参考

- [for...of - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)
- [Iteration protocols - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols)
- [ES6のイテレータについて調べた - ひよこ3分07秒のTechブログ](http://tech.chick307.com/2014/05/09/es6-iterator/)

Comment: 詳細解説ありがとうございました。Iteratorという概念を初めて知りました。リンク先等、大変参考になりました

Answer (score 1):

これですかね？

```
for (var k in hoge) {
    console.log(k + ' = ' + hoge[k]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ofはECMAScript6の書き方なので今はまだinで逃げるべきかと…
余分なプロトタイプチェーンのプロパティが出てくる場合はtypeofの判定を追加で。
    if (typeof(hoge[i]) !== 'function') {～～～}

```js
var hoge = {"area23": "東京", "area47": "沖縄"};
for (var i in hoge){
  alert(i+':'+hoge[i]);
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of
同じことをofでやる場合は下記のようですが・・・
自分の環境では確認できなかったり＾＾；

```
let hoge = {"area23": "東京", "area47": "沖縄"};
for (let i of hoge){
  alert(i);
}
```